# Android GSON POJO optional field parsing

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Ok so heres the thing I am working with an api that for one JSON parameter can return two different types. So I can receive from the server either a JSON Object or a String. I'm pretty new to Android development so if someone could explain to me with maybe a code example how I can handle that problem.

Example json responses {video:"ID OF VIDEO"} or {video:{id:"ID OF VIDEO",...extra data}}. I had a look at custom deserialisers but can't find an example that is easy to follow. There must be a simple way of solving my problem. Currently I receive error "Expected string but found BEGIN OBJECT"

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MyNotification {
    @SerializedName("_id")
    @Expose
    private String Id;
    @SerializedName("comment")
    @Expose
    private String comment;
    @SerializedName("createdAt")
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("read")
    @Expose
    private Boolean read;
    @SerializedName("recipient")
    @Expose
    private String recipient;
    @SerializedName("sender")
    @Expose
    private User sender;
    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;
//        @SerializedName("video")
//        @Expose
//        private String video;

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The Id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Id
     * The _id
     */
    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The comment
     */
    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param comment
     * The comment
     */
    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The createdAt
     */
    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param createdAt
     * The createdAt
     */
    public void setCreatedAt(String createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The message
     */
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param message
     * The message
     */
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The read
     */
    public Boolean getRead() {
        return read;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param read
     * The read
     */
    public void setRead(Boolean read) {
        this.read = read;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The recipient
     */
    public String getRecipient() {
        return recipient;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param recipient
     * The recipient
     */
    public void setRecipient(String recipient) {
        this.recipient = recipient;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The sender
     */
    public User getSender() {
        return sender;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param sender
     * The sender
     */
    public void setSender(User sender) {
        this.sender = sender;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The type
     */
    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param type
     * The type
     */
    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

//        /**
//         *
//         * @return
//         * The video
//         */
//        public String getVideo() {
//            return video;
//        }
//
//        /**
//         *
//         * @param video
//         * The video
//         */
//        public void setVideo(String video) {
//            this.video = video;
//        }

}
```

and the part that craps out

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = String.valueOf(dataset);
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<MyNotification>>(){}.getType();
notficationsList = (List<MyNotification>) gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);
```

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Post my code? Not really sure how that is going to be any help? Do you mean my POJO definition?

Comment: Yes your POJO definition could help, the Java part that throws the Exception too

Comment: Commented out the bits that were giving me troubles. I understand if I define it as a string it expects a string when converting JSON to pojo but there must be a way of handling that of which I am unaware.

Comment: where is the json created? is it a service of your own or an external one?

Comment: Comes from an external service. I just need gson to adapt based on that field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the solution I went with I wrote my own type adapter that gson allow you to use

```
public class Helper_StringAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String>{
@Override
public String read(com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader in) throws IOException {
   if(in.peek() == JsonToken.NULL){
       in.nextNull();
       return null;
   }else if(in.peek() == JsonToken.BEGIN_OBJECT && in.getPath().contains(".video")){
       L.e("VIDEO IS AN OBJECT!");
       String userId = readAndReturnVideoId(in);
       return userId;
   }else{
       return in.nextString();
   }
}

private String readAndReturnVideoId(com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader reader) throws IOException{
    String id = "";
    reader.beginObject();
    while(reader.hasNext()){
        String name = reader.nextName();
        if(name.equals("_id")){
            id = reader.nextString();
        }else{
            reader.skipValue();
        }
    }
    reader.endObject();
    L.e("READ ID RETURNED"+id);
    return id;
}

@Override
public void write(com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {
    L.e("TEST "+out);
}
}
```

Then in my activity data manager (Recyclerview Adapter)

```
public void updateData (JSONArray dataset) {
    GsonBuilder gsonb = new GsonBuilder();
    gsonb.registerTypeAdapter(String.class,new Helper_StringAdapter());
    Gson gson = gsonb.create();

    String jsonString = String.valueOf(dataset);
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<FrameNotification>>(){}.getType();
    notficationsList = (List<FrameNotification>) gson.fromJson(jsonString, listType);
}
```

Seems to do the job

Answer (score 1):

Sorry it took so long:

Your best bet is to repair the JSON, if you must map it to an Object.

Try cleaning the JSON with this code:

```
public static String cleanJson(String json) {
    int videoPos = json.indexOf("video");
    if(videoPos == -1) {
        return json; //return, no video here
    }
    boolean isObject = false;

    int objectBegin = -1;
    String cleanedJson = json.replaceAll("\\\"", "\\\\");
    for(int i = videoPos; i < cleanedJson.length(); i++) {
        if(cleanedJson.charAt(i) == '"') {
            System.out.println("string");
            return json; // its a string anyway
        }
        if(cleanedJson.charAt(i) == '{') {
            //its an object
            // i now is the position beginning the object
            objectBegin = i;
        }
    } //replace " with space
    if(objectBegin == -1) {// we did not find any { or " it is a string
        return json;
    }
    boolean inString = false;
    int objectEnd = -1;
    for(int i = objectBegin; i < cleanedJson.length(); i++) {
        //looking for the end of the object;
        if(cleanedJson.charAt(i) == '"') inString = !inString;
        if(cleanedJson.charAt(i) == '}') {
            objectEnd = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(objectEnd != -1) {
        String start = json.substring(0,objectBegin);
        String videoPart = json.substring(objectBegin, objectEnd+1);
        String end = json.substring(objectEnd+1);
        // now we want to get the id
        String newVideoPart = "";
        int idStart = videoPart.indexOf("id");
        int idStringStart = -1;
        int idStringEnd = -1;

        for(int i = idStart; i < videoPart.length(); i++) {
            if(videoPart.charAt(i) == '"') {
                if(idStringStart == -1) {
                    idStringStart = i;
                } else {
                    idStringEnd = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if(idStringStart != -1 && idStringEnd != -1) {
            newVideoPart = videoPart.substring(idStringStart, idStringEnd+1);
        }

        return start+newVideoPart+end;
    }
    return json;
}
```

Works with these two test jsons:

```
System.out.println(cleanJson("{video:\"1234\"}"));
System.out.println(cleanJson("{video:{id:\"2345\", name=\"test\"}}"));
```

Try it like this:

```
notficationsList = (List<MyNotification>) gson.fromJson(cleanJson(jsonString), listType);
```

Comment: i expected you need the vido id. of course you could turn it around and always make an object out of it. and you could make things simpler with libraries to. so the result is: you will always get the id of the video as a string called video

Comment: Ok I thought so. Thanks